# Javascript object instantiation of method

Tags: javascript, object, methods, instantiation

In Javascript, can you create an object instance of a method? My code below causes errors.

```
const myObject = {
    myMethod: function () {},
    objectInstance: new this.myMethod()
}
```

```
const myObject = {
    newObject: Object.create(null),
    objectInstance: new newObject()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```js
   // Use class for declaring myObject
   class myObject  {
     constructor(textArg) {
       this.text = textArg;
       this.objectInstance = function (){return new myObject(this.text);}
     }
  }
  // First myObject instance
  let myObject_instance_1 = new myObject("myObject instance 1");
  console.log(myObject_instance_1.objectInstance().text);// output: myObject instance 1
  // Second myObject instance
  let myObject_instance_2 = new myObject("myObject instance 2");
  console.log(myObject_instance_2.objectInstance().text); // output: myObject instance 2

  let myObject_instance_3 = myObject_instance_2 ;
  // Should be the same text as myObject_instance_2 text
  console.log(myObject_instance_3.objectInstance().text); // output: myObject instance 2
```

**EDIT**

**Singleton Pattern**

```js
const SingletonClass = (function () {
let instance;
 
function createInstance() {
    let object = new Object("I am the instance");
    return object;
}
 
return {
    getInstance: function () {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = createInstance();
        }
        return instance;
    }
};
 })(); 
function testSingelton() { 
    let instance1 = SingletonClass.getInstance();
    let instance2 = SingletonClass.getInstance();
 
    alert("\"instance1\" is same instance as \"instance2\"?  Answer: " + 
    (instance1 === instance2));  
}
testSingelton();
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because of the this context. In this context there is none myMethod function then it throws error. If you convert to this it could solve problem.

const myObject = {
myMethod: function () {},
objectInstance:null,
setObjectInstance:function(){
this.objectInstance= return new this.myMethod()
}

}
Then you can initialize object instance like this.
myObject.setObjectInstance()